# Change version of pmml XML file R

Tags: r, pmml

Is there a way to change the version of the pmml file? The current pmml() function returns version 4.4 whilst I want version 4.3. I don't want to download previous versions of the pmml package or manually change the returned XML file. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should try out the [r2pmml](https://cran.r-project.org/package=r2pmml) package, which can do everything that the legacy [pmml](https://cran.r-project.org/package=pmml) package does, and then some more.

Otherwise, you'd need to download a previous version of the legacy pmml package, or manually change the XML namespace declaration of the returned XML file - there is no other way.